# React and redux-tookit: How to dispatch action when other action completed?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am trying to show a snackbar whenever a deletion succeeds. I created an action for that.

Where do I dispatch that action?

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
export const deleteSelectedEntry = createAsyncThunk('entries/delete/selected', async (id: string) => {
    const response = await BackendService.deleteEntry(id);
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    dispatch(setSnackBarState({
        state: true,
        message: "SUCCESS DELETING"
    }));
    return response.data
})
```

This is an async thunk in one of the slice classes that you create when using the redux toolkit.

I created a hook for the dispatch method as per redux-toolkit's suggestion in the tutorial:

```
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
```

But wherever I think I should be able to put the dispatch method, I get an error that I cannot use the react hook there.

My initial attempt was putting it in the extraReducers:

```
extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
        .addCase(deleteSelectedEntry.fulfilled, (state: MyState, action: PayloadAction<Entry>) => {
            // do Stuff
        })
```

How do you then dispatch actions from other actions in react redux? I have seen examples on StackOverflow where people used the useDispatch method in an asyncThunk.

Help and tipps appreciated!

If necessary, I'll post more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your initial intuition was correct, in using the `extraReducers` slice property. Here is how I have done for what I call a "notificationSlice":

```
import { createEntityAdapter, createSlice, isAnyOf } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {
  doStuffPage1
} from './page1.slice'

import {
  doStuffPage2
} from './page2.slice'

const notificationsAdapter = createEntityAdapter()

const initialState = notificationsAdapter.getInitialState({
  error: null,
  success: null,
  warning: null,
  info: null,
})

const notificationsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notifications',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      // set success on fulfilled
      .addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(
          doStuffPage1.fulfilled,
          doStuffPage2.fulfilled,
        ),
        (state, action) => {
          state.error = null
          state.warning = null
          state.success = action.payload.message
        }
      )
      // set error on rejections
      .addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(
          doStuffPage1.rejected,
          doStuffPage2.rejected,
        ),
        (state, action) => {
          state.error = action?.payload
          state.warning = null
          state.success = null
        }
      )
      // reset all messages on pending
      .addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(
          doStuffPage1.pending,
          doStuffPage2.pending,
        ),
        (state, action) => {
          state.error = null
          state.success = null
          state.warning = null
        }
      )
  },
})
export const {
  clearNotifications,
  setError,
  setSuccess,
  setWarning,
  setInfo,
} = notificationsSlice.actions

export default notificationsSlice.reducer

export const getErrorMsg = state => state.notifications.error
export const getSuccessMsg = state => state.notifications.success
export const getInfoMsg = state => state.notifications.info
export const getWarningMsg = state => state.notifications.warning
```

Some things to note:

- The selectors will be imported somewhere in a high level component, and additional snackbar logic will be used THERE
- You need to ensure that your thunks (doStuffPage1/doStuffPage2) are returning messages with their success/error results

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work now using this approach